# How to avoid needless rebuilds with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Stack usually caches package dependency builds to save time in future builds, but I've noticed many cases in practice where this doesn't happen.  When it works, it can be a huge time-saver, as building dependencies can often take like half an hour or more.

After some work I've been able to isolate a simple example which illustrates this problem, and was wondering if someone could help me fix it.  Note, this problem only refers to new builds, like after a clone....  The second build of the same clone does in fact go quickly.

---

If I compile this very simple Main.hs

```
import Network.Haskoin.Internals

main = undefined
```

using this stack.yaml

```
resolver: lts-2.15
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps: 
- haskoin-0.1.0.2
- json-rpc-0.2.1.6
- pbkdf-1.1.1.1
- text-1.1.1.4

flags: {}
```

and this .cabal file

```
name:                simple
version:             0.1.0.0
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable simple-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , haskoin
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

stack will rebuild every dependency every time I re-clone the source code.

I am guessing that it might have something to do with the `extra-deps`, in particular `text-1.1.1.4`, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that once you have selected a resolver, stack will "cache" a package if:

1. The package is in Stackage for the resolver, and
2. The package is built with exactly the same set of dependency-versions specified by the resolver.

The package-versions selected by the resolver LTS-2.15 may be found on this page:

https://www.stackage.org/lts-2.15

The "cache" on your machine for the resolver LTS-2.15 is located in a directory like:

```
~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-2.15/7.8.4/pkgdb
```

For instance, your project uses `blaze-builder-0.4.0.1` which is in Stackage LTS-2.15. However, `blaze-builder` depends on `text`, and if you were using the version of `text` in LTS-2.15 (namely `text-1.2.0.6`) then stack would cache `blaze-builder-0.4.0.1` in the LTS-2.15 snapshot directory (assuming all of the other dependencies for `blaze-builder` matched the versions in LTS-2.15.) However, since you have specified version 1.1.1.4 for `text`, stack will not save the resulting `blaze-builder` in the LTS-2.15 snapshot directory. It will be saved in the `.stack-work` directory for the project.

Since so many packages depend on `text`, my recommendation would be to use a version of `text` which is listed in a Stackage resolver.

Comment: Related: there was just a discussion in the Stack issue tracker about caching extra-deps: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1029.  Using a [custom snapshot](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Custom-Snapshot) may help.